# How to: django template pass array and use it in javascript?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates

Ok so here is a problem, 
   I have an html template which looks something like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var vCountries = {{ visitedCountriesList }};
    });
</script>

<..>

{{ visitedCountriesList }}
```

from server I pass an list to this item, but after rendering it looks like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
            var vCountries = ;
        });
    </script>

    <..>

    [u'Afghanistan', u'Japan', u'United Arab Emirates']
```

so my question is - why ? and how I can pass it to javascript...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have in your html an id with the variable rendered and look it there, lets do an example:

```
<...>
    <loldiv id="myvar" data="{{info}}"/>
<...>
```

and in your javascript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var vCountries = $("#myvar").attr("data");
});
</script>
```

That is assuming you are using jQuery.

I dont really know why that template assign the variable but you should not render any information on javascript code since there is a moment where you are going to take that js and put it on a compressed file, or move it, or reuse it and it will be really hard to do it if you rendered the variable values that way.

hope this helps!

Comment: ok, and how do you convert from data="[u'Afghanistan', u'Japan', u'United Arab Emirates']" to an array object in js?

Comment: you should encode the list as a json and decode it in your javascript.

from django.utils import simplejson
vcountries = simplejson.dumps(vcountries)

and send that from your view and decode the variable with a JSON.parse on your javascript

Comment: There's no need to do this - after json encoding, it can simply be inserted as a string into the Javascript.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the string representation of the array isn't valid JavaScript. The `u'` at the start is no good. This:

```
[u'Afghanistan', u'Japan', u'United Arab Emirates']
```

should be this:

```
['Afghanistan', 'Japan', 'United Arab Emirates']
```

You have two options. In the view function, encode it as JSON there there:

```
render_to_response('my_view.html', {
    'visitedCountriesList' : json.dumps(visitedCountriesList)
})
```

or create a filter that you can use. See [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/201/) one for an example. Then usage is just:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var vCountries = {{ visitedCountriesList|jsonify }};
  });
</script>
```